# Sticky side bar doesn't allows total scroll down when it's bigger than main div

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, sticky

I have a page which has a header a footer a div to display results and another one to display a sidebar provide some filter options for those results and a google maps map so the user can search moving the map. Whe the map is moved, it makes a ajax call and repopulates the div using PHP, the problem is, everytime I make the ajax call and the number of results returned to the main div is too small, making this result div smaller than the filter div, it doesn't allows me to scroll down to the bottom of the page, when I try to to this it throws my scroll bar to the top as soon as I reach the bottom.

```
$(function(){ // document ready

    if (!!$('#filterswrap').offset()) { // make sure "sticky" element exists

        var stickyTop = $('#filterswrap').offset().top; // returns number
        var footerTop = $('.footerwrap').offset().top; // returns number
        var filtersWrap = $('#filterswrap').height(); //filter bar's size
        var resultsWrap = $('#resultswrap').height(); //result bar' size


        $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event

            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
            var limit = footerTop - filtersWrap - 80;

            if(filtersWrap > resultsWrap) // only apply if necessary
            {
                $('#filterswrap').css('position','static');
                return false;
            }

            if (stickyTop < windowTop)
            {
                $('#filterswrap').css({ position: 'fixed', top: -50, left: 933});
            }
            else
            {
                $('#filterswrap').css('position','static');
            }

            //Stops at the footer's top
            if (limit < windowTop)
            {
                var diff = limit - windowTop;
                $('#filterswrap').css({top: diff});
            }

        });
    }

});
```

As you can see, I've tried to prevent the side bar's div to be set as static when it's bigger than the results div, however it only works for the first call, when the first Ajax call is made it doesn't work anymore.

Does anyone know what I can do to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: could you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: I'll do this, thanks!